# Pywinauto - Wait for process to end without timeout

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I've got a python script 3.9.7 64-bit that uses PyWinAuto to automate an application.

I have a long operation in my application

and the app raise an exception of timeout while trying two ways of doing it

Is there a way to wait for process to end without timeout?

first way :

```
Application(backend="uia").start(reg360path)
reg360App = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=reg360path, title='Cyclone REGISTER 360')        
       
      while(reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.Publishing.exists()):
        if(reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.PublishResults.exists()):
            break
```

second way:

```
Application(backend="uia").start(reg360path)
reg360App = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=reg360path, title='Cyclone REGISTER 360')            
        
  publishing_is_on = False
  while not publishing_is_on:
   if(reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.PublishResults.wait('enabled')):
         publishing_is_on = True
```

Both ways raise error timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `wait()` and `exists()` have parameter `timeout`. Just set large enough timeout in seconds:

```
# wait for up to 10 minutes
reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.PublishResults.wait('enabled', timeout=600)

# or
reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.child_window(title="Publishing").wait_not('exists', timeout=600)

# or
reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.PublishResults.exists(timeout=600)
```

Exact matching for `title="Publishing"` is better because usual attribute access `.Publishing` is resistant to a typo. Words "Publishing" and "PublishResults" may be too similar (I didn't test it, it's just a guess).

Comment: Thank you 

"Exact matching for title="Publishing" is better" This change worked for me.
Its true the two titles were too similar, so you guessed it right.

Im using this solution 
- reg360App.CycloneREGISTER360.child_window(title=".Publish Results", found_index=0).exists()

Thank you

Comment: BTW - I'm not using the timeout param and it's still working for me (Because the process I'm using can take every time different hours to complete. So it's quit not efficient to set timeout to this process)